# Can you recover files from an overwritten RAID 1?

Tags: raid1, data-recovery

Edit:
The array is actually RAID1, slight communication hiccup with the rest of my team.

Following the decommissioning of one of our server, a manager just realised there was, after all, data that he needed from that server. Now due to proper protocol not being followed, the server was re-imaged before a complete backup was taken and we're past our 5-week retention period. The raid 1 array in question was the system volume and those 2 hdd have since been reconfigured in a new RAID 1 and a new OS was installed. RAID controller is HP Smart Array P400i/256MB Controller.

Comment: You haven't asked a question but it seems likely that your data is gone. RAId 0 is for people who hate their data.

Comment: The question was in the title. I did forget to end it with a question mark maybe that would make it clearer or should I repeat in in the body?

Comment: The only thing that RAID1 would change over RAID0 is that you could send in one drive to a data recovery outfit instead of two. Even so, with the volume being reconfigured and written with new data, it's a slim chance it will be worth it.

Answer (score 3):

1. Why on earth are you using a RAID0? You clearly have important information on this server (otherwise you wouldn't be wanting to restore it), and by using RAID0 you are doubling your risk of data loss.
2. The chances of being able to recover data is slim. Your best bet would be to send them to a professional data recovery firm like [Kroll Ontrack](https://www.krollontrack.com/services/data-recovery/). Beware, though, it's going to be expensive.

Comment: Well, that drive wasn't supposed to have anything important it was just the OS. I have no idea why the data file of this one database was left on it as I've just discovered and I can't say I'm happy with whoever set that up. That is however the situation I'm stuck with and I'll do whatever I can to make the best of it. Also, I can't help but fell that your comment was directed at me because, well.. who else would it hurt, but I didn't. If it's not possible it's not possible. Even if I wanted to I couldn't, not having enough reputation and all.

Answer (score 2):

There's no simple way of recovering from that.  *IF* the blocks in question haven't  been overwritten by the new OS, then it is *possible* that a data recovery company could recover that.  Its going to be a question of how valuable that data is to the company vs the cost to attempt recovery which may not yield any results.

Edit: Raid1 makes recovery somewhat simpler as all the data is on one drive, but still chancy.

Answer (score 1):

This is a definitely a loss if a new HP Smart Array and RAID metadata were written to the drive for two reasons:

- Reconstructing from RAID 0 is very difficult.
- The array has been reconfigured and new data written.

You did all you can do... your retention period was reasonable, but sometimes you have to tell the business users, "*tough luck... the data is gone!*"